# What should the endpoint be for a Keycloak IDP initiated SSO?

Tags: keycloak

I managed to run the [saml-broker-authentication](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak/tree/3.2.1.Final/examples/broker/saml-broker-authentication) example.

SP initiated SSO works OK.

What should the IDP initiated SSO url be? Thanks.

Comment: Mailing list: http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-October/011943.html

Answer (score -1):

See http://www.keycloak.org/docs/latest/server_admin/topics/clients/saml/idp-initiated-login.html:

> In the Settings tab for your client, you need to
>   specify the *IDP Initiated SSO URL Name*. This is a simple string with
>   no whitespace in it. After this you can reference your client at the
>   following URL:
>   root/auth/realms/*{realm}*/protocol/saml/clients/*{url-name}*

Comment: Do you know of a Keycloak example that supports idp-initiated sso?

Comment: Got an answer in mailing list:
Any SAML application, e.g.
https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-quickstarts/tree/latest/app-profile-saml-jee-jsp.
\* http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2017-October/011954.html

Comment: So what should the IDP initiated SSO URL look like?